# When my screen is locked, will running processes/internet connection be halted?

Tags: lock-screen

Sometimes I leave my PC doing other stuff while running an upgrade or downloading big files, Syncing my Dropbox, or something like that. After 10mins or so, my screen is locked (which I like).

I just wanted to know if running processes or the Internet connection will be locked too when that happens. Because I don't want to do that stuff after I get back on my PC again.

And if that's the case (halted processes), Is there a way to keep processes / connection running while the screen is locked?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I think there has to be some option for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My answer to your question is **It should not**.
As far as i have been using Ubuntu i have seen processes stopping only when it is told to do so (I use a rhythmbox plugin which stops playing msic when the screnn gets locked without that plugin the music goes on.). Also i do the same thing that you do i.e lock the screen and keep stuff for syncing, downloading etc but it has never happened that the process gets stopped.

Comment: Welcome!!! :) :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the program terminates as the screen closes(the ubuntu way). You need to mention the services to go on by

```
screen your_program_name
```

you can close screen with `crtl-a-d` then reopen it later with `screen -rx`