# stop using internet when screen blanks

Tags: networking, internet, lock-screen

Related: [When my screen is locked, will running processes/internet connection be halted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131983/when-my-screen-is-locked-will-running-processes-internet-connection-be-halted)

This is related, but exactly the opposite is desired.

I recently installed the (really terrific) Radio Tray, but I've noticed that it keeps streaming from the internet after the screen blanks even though the sound is off (as I would expect). I know this is desirable behavior so that updates, downloads, and so forth can continue while I'm away from the machine, but the radio (music) streaming is just dumping to the proverbial bit-bucket - wasting bandwidth (not a lot, but still).

Is there a way to control this activity - preferably on a per-app basis - when the screen blanks?

Thanks for any pointers.